# There is not linear transformation such that...

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that there is not a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to the space of degree 2 polynomials such that $T(2,1,0)=1+x$, $T(3,0,2)=2-x+x^2$ and $T(0,6,-8)=-2+2x^2$.

The only observation I could made was that we have a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$ but it goes to a not linearly independent set, but I think basis go to basis only if the transformation is injective, which I don't know here.

Is there any other way I can derive a contradiction here?

Comment: Sometimes a reasonable way to go about these is to use the given information and lienarity to figure out what $T(0)$ is. If it's not $0$, there's no such transformation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe $6\cdot T(2,1,0)-4\cdot T(3,0,2)=T(0,6,-8)$ and try to see the contradiction.